# Como fazer requisição á arquivos PHP e BD, no mesmo servidor criado pelo React-app

Tags: react

Eu estou aprendendo a usar o Framework React. Na parte de envio de dados de formulário, e recuperar esses dados, estou usando ajax com a função do jQuery.

```
componentDidMount() {

    $.ajax({
      url:"http://localhost:80/contatos/dados-json.php",
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(clientes){
        this.setState({lista:clientes});
      }.bind(this)
    });
}
```

Só que essa URL a quem estou fazendo a requisição é de outro servidor que está local na minha máquina (um servidor Xampp).

**Traduzindo, são dois servidores Locais na mesma máquina**

No caso está assim:

1. React está - localhost:3000 (npm create-react-app)
2. Arquivos PHP e BD - localhost:80 (Xampp)

O problema disso é que fico fazendo requisições em servidor cruzado, e acaba dando mais problemas para funcionar.

Queria saber como faço para colocar: **Arquivos PHP e BD** no mesmo servidor do React?

Comment: O sevidor PHP está na mesma máquina do REACT, mas em servidores locais diferentes, um ta no localhost:3000 e o outro localhost:80, da forma que ta ai, ta funcionando, mas é complicado pq é servidor cruzado, eu quero colocar esses arquivos PHP e o BD no mesmo servidor do REACT entendes? @wmsouza

Comment: Eu estou usando, npm create-react-app, já vem com node,webpack etc instalado

Comment: Aplicação React:
C:\Users\W8\Desktop\curso-react

Arquivos PHP: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\contatos

Comment: Pegue os arquivos, HTML e JavaScript que foi compilado pelo Webpack e coloque dentro de um diretório em seu servidor **PHP**.

Comment: Mas ai perco os recursos do node.js? ou o react vai usar da mesma forma?

Comment: Os recursos que sua aplicação vai utilizar vai ser compactada pelo Webpack, sua aplicação vai funcionar normalmente, só que por um servidor **PHP**. É como você colocasse seu site no servidor, e pronto.

Comment: Hum entendi vlw

Comment: Rodrigo, você conseguiu uma solução? Estou com o mesmo problema